# Database table update fails to happen upload file upload

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a SQL Server database table called `ProductProfiles`, which contains products and their information (one product per line). On the site I'm working on, users can upload a `.csv` file with changes to any or all of the columns for a product or products.

I have a function that sets up an `UPDATE` query that is meant to replace any "old" information with new information from the `.csv` file. I don't appear to be getting any errors (the `try-catch` does not report any errors and I see no errors in the console).

Yet, whenever a valid `.csv` file with changes is uploaded, these changes never make into the database. I tested the `UPDATE` query in SQL Server Management Studio and it seems to work fine.

This function has the `UPDATE` query:

```
private void SaveProfile(string[] curProfile)
{
    string profid = "";
    //have an update and an insert statement based on whether the profileid exists or is new
    string ProfileID = GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId).Trim();
    string getProfId = "SELECT ProfileID FROM ProductProfile WHERE ProfileID = @ProfileID";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getProfId, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", ProfileID);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cn.Open();
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
                while (reader.Read())
           {
               profid = reader["ProfileID"].ToString();

               if (profid != "")
               {
                   try
                   {
                       string query = "UPDATE ProductProfile SET (Name = @Name, Description = @Description, SpeciesLink = @SpeciesLink, LineDraw = @LineDraw, LineDrawThumbnail = @LineDrawThumbnail, ProfileThumbnail = @ProfileThumbnail, ComponentThickness = @ComponentThickness, ComponentWidth = @ComponentWidth, FinishedThickness = @FinishedThickness, FinishedWidth = @FinishedWidth, ClassificationID = @ClassificationID, StockOfCust = @StockOrCust, ComponentFactor = @ComponentFactor, Visibility = @Visibility, Notes = @Notes) WHERE ProfileID = @profid";

                       SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                       // cn.Open();
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profid", profid);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Name).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Description).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpeciesLink", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.SpeciesLink).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Linedraw", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.LineDraw).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineDrawThumbnail", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.LineDrawThumbnail).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileThumbnail", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileThumbnail).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentThickness", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentThickness).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentWidth", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentWidth).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishedThickness", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedThickness).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishedWidth", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedWidth).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassificationID", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ClassificationID).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockOrCust", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.StockOrCust).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentFactor", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentFactor).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visibility", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Visibility).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Notes).Trim());
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.OrderBy).Trim());

                       int profileID = Convert.ToInt32(GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId));
                       SaveArtchStyle(profileID, curProfile);
                       SaveAssignedItems(profileID, curProfile);
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString() + "<br />");
                       ErrorLabel.Text = "There was an error with the ProfileID.";
                   }
               }
            }
         }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

This function calls the `SaveProfile` function:

```
protected void ProcessFileAction(string theStream)
{
    try
    {
        int LineCount = 1;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theStream))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (LineCount > 1 && line.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    string[] tmpArray = line.Split('\t');
                    //save changes
                    string ProfileID = GetValue(tmpArray, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId);
                    if (ProfileID != "")
                        SaveProfile(tmpArray);
                }
                LineCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        Response.Write("ProcessFileAction Error: " + x.Message.ToString() + "<br />");
    }
    //ErrorLabel.Text += "Import Complete on <b><i>" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "</i></b><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception mentioned in the question title?  What is the state of the runtime objects when that happens?  Have you done *any* debugging on this?  When you step through with a debugger, where does it fail?

Comment: You did notice that there is no OrderBy parameter used in your update statement?

Comment: You are mixing up two SqlCommands. You have one assinged to `cmd` to run the select query (*Why?*) and then assign the SqlCommand update query to `cmd2`. The parameters however are added to `cmd` and then outside your loop you call `ExecuteNonQuery` on cmd where you should have used `cmd2`. Conclusion: Your code never calls your update query hence no updates in the database.

Comment: @rene: and in addition, `cmd2` which contains the `UPDATE` is never executed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
private void SaveProfile(string[] curProfile)
{
    string profid = "";
    //have an update and an insert statement based on whether the profileid exists or is new
    string ProfileID = GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId).Trim();
    string getProfId = "SELECT ProfileID FROM ProductProfile WHERE ProfileID = @ProfileID";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getProfId, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", ProfileID);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cn.Open();
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
                while (reader.Read())
           {
               profid = reader["ProfileID"].ToString();

               if (profid != "")
               {
                   try
                   {
                       string query = "UPDATE ProductProfile SET (Name = @Name, Description = @Description, SpeciesLink = @SpeciesLink, LineDraw = @LineDraw, LineDrawThumbnail = @LineDrawThumbnail, ProfileThumbnail = @ProfileThumbnail, ComponentThickness = @ComponentThickness, ComponentWidth = @ComponentWidth, FinishedThickness = @FinishedThickness, FinishedWidth = @FinishedWidth, ClassificationID = @ClassificationID, StockOfCust = @StockOrCust, ComponentFactor = @ComponentFactor, Visibility = @Visibility, Notes = @Notes) WHERE ProfileID = @profid";

                       SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                       cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profid", profid);
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Name).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Description).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpeciesLink", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.SpeciesLink).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Linedraw", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.LineDraw).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineDrawThumbnail", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.LineDrawThumbnail).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileThumbnail", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileThumbnail).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentThickness", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentThickness).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentWidth", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentWidth).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishedThickness", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedThickness).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishedWidth", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.FinishedWidth).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassificationID", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ClassificationID).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockOrCust", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.StockOrCust).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentFactor", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ComponentFactor).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visibility", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Visibility).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.Notes).Trim());
                       cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.OrderBy).Trim());

                       int profileID = Convert.ToInt32(GetValue(curProfile, (int)ProfileColumns.ProfileId));
                       SaveArtchStyle(profileID, curProfile);
                       SaveAssignedItems(profileID, curProfile);

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString() + "<br />");
                       ErrorLabel.Text = "There was an error with the ProfileID.";
                   }
               }
            }
         }
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```